# How to update subdocuments in MongoDB with Mongoose, Express, and Node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I have a **Mongoose** Model called `Profile`:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: "user",
  },
  company: {
    type: String,
  },
  website: {
    type: String,
  },
  location: {
    type: String,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  skills: {
    type: [String],
    required: true,
  },
  bio: {
    type: String,
  },
  githubusername: {
    type: String,
  },
  experience: [{
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    company: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    location: {
      type: String,
    },
    from: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
    },
    to: {
      type: Date,
    },
    current: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
    },
  }, ],
  education: [{
    school: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    degree: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    fieldofstudy: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    from: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
    },
    to: {
      type: Date,
    },
    current: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
    },
  }, ],
  social: {
    youtube: {
      type: String,
    },
    twitter: {
      type: String,
    },
    facebook: {
      type: String,
    },
    linkedin: {
      type: String,
    },
    instagram: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model("profile", ProfileSchema);
```

As you can see I have a bunch of nested subdocuments and I want to be able to update them. In particular I want to be able to able to update the `experience` with a `PUT` endpoint.

Here is the endpoint to add an experience:

```js
router.put(
  "/experience", [
    auth, [
      check("title", "Title is required").not().isEmpty(),
      check("company", "Company is required").not().isEmpty(),
      check("from", "From date is required and needs to be from the past")
      .not()
      .isEmpty()
      .custom((value, {
        req
      }) => (req.body.to ? value < req.body.to : true)),
    ],
  ],
  async(req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        errors: errors.array()
      });
    }

    const {
      title,
      company,
      location,
      from,
      to,
      current,
      description,
    } = req.body;

    const newExp = {
      title,
      company,
      location,
      from,
      to,
      current,
      description,
    };

    try {
      const profile = await Profile.findOne({
        user: req.user.id
      });

      profile.experience.unshift(newExp);

      await profile.save();

      res.json(profile);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    }
  }
);
```

And this works I am able to add an `experience` to that array. 
But When I try and Update it does not work here is what I have tried:

```js
router.put("/experience/:exp_id", auth, async(req, res) => {
  try {
    const profile = await Profile.experience.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params._id, {
        $set: req.body,
      }, {
        new: true
      }
    );
    res.json(profile);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).json({
      msg: "Server error"
    });
  }
});
```

I get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'findByIdAndUpdate' of undefined` what am I doing wrong?

Here is a some `Profile` data I have when I create a `Profile`

```js
{
  "social": {
    "youtube": "https://youtube.com/user/mojara2009",
    "twitter": null,
    "instagram": null,
    "linkedin": "https://linkedin.com/in/amen-ra",
    "facebook": null
  },
  "skills": [
    " HTML",
    " CSS",
    " JAVASCRIPT",
    " REACT",
    " REDUX",
    " JEST"
  ],
  "_id": "5eb1a19b83001bdb87e26492",
  "user": {
    "_id": "5eb10fecc3de3526caba5e50",
    "name": "Amen Ra",
    "avatar": "//www.gravatar.com/avatar/ee452fcb90a3913ca75ed4b4f06c4de6?s=200&r=pg&d=mm"
  },
  "__v": 19,
  "bio": "I am a Senior Full Stack Developer for Web App Company",
  "company": "Web App Company",
  "githubusername": "mojaray2k",
  "location": "Aventura, Fl",
  "status": "Developer",
  "website": "https://imaginationeverywhere.info",
  "date": "2020-05-05T22:33:41.596Z",
  "education": [{
      "current": false,
      "_id": "5eb2eccd659559371b2162f4",
      "school": "Bethune-Cookman University",
      "degree": "Bachelor of Arts",
      "fieldofstudy": "Mass Communication",
      "from": "1994-08-04T00:00:00.000Z",
      "to": "1999-04-26T00:00:00.000Z",
      "description": "Attended Bethune Cookman College in Daytona Beach, Fl"
    },
    {
      "current": false,
      "_id": "5eb2ecc2659559371b2162f3",
      "school": "Manual High School",
      "degree": "Diploma",
      "fieldofstudy": "NA",
      "from": "1990-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "to": "1994-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "description": "Attended High School my sophomore through senior year"
    },
    {
      "current": false,
      "_id": "5eb2ecb5659559371b2162f2",
      "school": "John F. Kennedy High School",
      "degree": "NA",
      "fieldofstudy": "NA",
      "from": "1989-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "to": "1990-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "description": "Attended High School my sophomore through senior year"
    },
    {
      "current": false,
      "_id": "5eb2ea28659559371b2162eb",
      "school": "Kunsmiller",
      "degree": "NA",
      "fieldofstudy": "Middle School",
      "from": "1988-02-01T05:00:00.000Z",
      "to": "1989-06-01T04:00:00.000Z",
      "description": "Attended Middle School There"
    }
  ],
  "experience": [{
      "current": false,
      "_id": "5eb356f74cc1ad499167567d",
      "title": "Senior Full Stack Engineer",
      "company": "Concept Solutions",
      "location": "Aventura, Fl",
      "from": "2016-01-03T00:00:00.000Z",
      "to": "2018-02-28T00:00:00.000Z",
      "description": "Worked as Full Stack Developer"
    },
    {
      "current": false,
      "_id": "5eb2de8fccd73b25fd1b2b39",
      "title": "Senior Full Stack Engineer",
      "company": "Jehovah Jireh, Inc",
      "location": "Aventura, Fl",
      "from": "2018-07-01T04:00:00.000Z",
      "to": "2019-07-01T04:00:00.000Z",
      "description": "Worked as Full Stack Developer"
    },
    {
      "current": true,
      "_id": "5eb203af1e004371b3284883",
      "title": "Senior Full Stack Engineer",
      "company": "Web App Company",
      "location": "Aventura, Fl",
      "from": "2019-07-01T04:00:00.000Z",
      "description": "Worked as Full Stack Developer"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @Fayad That does not work

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to access a mongoose model schema as a Profile object. Instead if you want to update a specific part of the model, in this case `experience`, you can do as follows:

```js
try {
    const await profile = Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
        { experience: { $elemMatch: { _id: req.params.exp_id } } },
        { $set: { 'experience.$': req.body } },
        { new: true }
    );
    res.json(profile);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Server error' });
}
```

Also I believe it be `req.params.exp_id` instead of `req.params._id`.

Comment: That does not work. This is the error I am getting `Cannot read property 'findByIdAndUpdate' of undefined`

Comment: Do you have a reference to the model, something like `var Profile = require('PATH_TO_PERSON_MODEL')`

Comment: This is what I have imported `const Profile = require("../../models/Profile");`

Comment: I have edited my answer incase you have copied it, since I have put `Person` instead of `Profile` by mistake, let me know if that was the case.

Comment: What do you put in the `callback`? Because I am getting null.

Comment: If you do not need it, then you can just no put it.

Comment: So I closed off the `const` and I then put `res.json(profile);` and I get `null` and the `experience` is not updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213295/discussion-between-fayad-and-amen-ra).

Answer (score 0):

Thats a normal response for mongoose, Because Profile is a **Collection Model Schema**, not an **Profile object**. Also if you want to update an specific element on the array, You need to add query to help mongo to find which data will only update on the array.

Here's the alternate query for updating collection data on mongo.

```js
    router.put("/:profile_id/experience/:exp_id", auth, async(req, res) => {
     const {profile_id = '', exp_id = ''} = req.params
      try {
        const profile = await Profile.findOne(
          {
             _id: mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(profile_id)
          }
        );
        if (!profile) {
           throw new Error('No profile found.')
        }
        const index = profile.experience.findIndex((exp) => exp._id === mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(exp_id))
        if (index === -1) {
           throw new Error('No experience data found.')
        }
        const {_id, ...experience} = req.body
        profile.experience[index] = experience
        profile.save
        res.json(profile);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).json({
          msg: "Server error"
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: I get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'experience' of null`

Comment: I think  thats mean that the exp id is not existing on the profile collection

Comment: This is what the experience array looks like:
  experience[  {
            "current": false,
            "_id": "5eb356f74cc1ad499167567d",
            "title": "Senior Full Stack Engineer",
            "company": "Concept Innovations",
            "location": "Aventura, Fl",
            "from": "2016-01-03T00:00:00.000Z",
            "to": "2018-02-28T00:00:00.000Z",
            "description": "Worked as Full Stack Developer"
        }]

Comment: ohh. i think you need to convert the _id or exp_id inside of the "req.body" from string to ObjectId of mongoose.

Comment: Yeah the root object also has an `_id` along with `experience` which each one has it's own `_id`

Comment: okay. so how about the `req.body`? it is also have an `_id` property on it?

Comment: Yes it does. It has it's own `ObjectId`

Comment: Okay, are you sure that the `req.params.exp_id` is for profile root `_id`? or its for `experience ` property inside of the profile collection?

Comment: I added the actual data I am trying to operate on.

Comment: Ok. I will update the snippet above to convert the `req.params._id` and `req.body._id` to ObjectId.

Comment: Now I am getting this error `Error: No profile found.`

Comment: and thats great. now we know that the `req.params.exp_id` is not existing on the profile collection. i think the implementation is wrong, are you sure that the `exp_id` is a `profile _id`? not a `experience _id`?

Comment: Yeap I posted the whole profile object above as my last snippet.

Comment: But that's a sample data of one `profile` object. what i am telling is the http request that you are using for updating the experience property. because the error tell us that the `exp_id ` you passed on the `url params` is not existing on your `profile ` collection data list.

Comment: Oh my fault I read your last comment wrong. The profile_id is not the exp_id.

Comment: I suggest to pass the `profile_id` and the `exp_id` on the url params to make your query more accurate.

Comment: How would you suggest that? Can you update your snippet?

Comment: Okay, I already update the snippet above, but you also need to update your http request to add the `profile_id` on the `url params`

Comment: So I did this `const { profile_id = "_id", exp_id = "experience._id" } = req.params;` but I am getting this error `Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters at new ObjectID `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213300/discussion-between-darryl-fabian-and-amen-ra).

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```
const profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate
```

instead of const profile = await Profile.experience.findByIdAndUpdate